# How to display an object property in a drop down list in VB.Net/C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am working with VB.Net and ASP.net, but C# code are welcome too.

I have a list of Clients, the client attributes are:

-ClientID
-FullName

Sample data:

-ClientID:1
-FullName:John Binder

-ClientID:2
-FullName:Leah Brown

And I have a list of Agreements "lstAgreements", their attributes are:

-AgreementID
-ClientID
-Date

Sample data:

AgreementID:5
ClientID:2
Date:12/30/16

AgreementID:7
ClientID:1
Date:12/29/16

"Client" and "Agreement" are entities classes with an existing relation:One client can have many Agreements.

I can retrieve all the agreements with:

```
 Dim lstAgreements As List(Of Agreement) =GetAllAgreements()
```

And the Agreement Class has a property to get the client object:

```
lstAgreements(0).ClientObject.FullName
```

Then I can populate a drop down list with "lstAgreements"

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = lstAgreements 
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "AgreementID"
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "ClientID"
myDropDownList.DataBind()
```

My question is, how can I display "ClientFullName" instead "ClientID" in the drop Down List?

I am trying this code but it does not work:

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = lstAgreements 
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "AgreementID"
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "ClientObject.FullName"
myDropDownList.DataBind()
```

I noticed that using "ClientObject.FullName" in a DataList control it works fine, but in Drop Down List it doesn't.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through lst Agreements rather than using a datasource/databind and create the list items yourself?

something like

```
foreach (Agreement a in lstAgreements)
{
     myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(a.ClientObject.FullName, a.AgreementId))
}
```

or use linq to set your full name from the client list if you have no full name method to return full name in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you just use it like this :

```
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "FullName";
```

**Update**:

> Obviously , Agreement does not contain a property with the name 'FullName'. it has -AgreementID -ClientID -Date properties.

I would recommend using Linq to retrive the data you need from multiple lists (C#):

```
public class CustomList
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int AgreementID{ get; set; }
}

var Custom = from i in listofClients
             from j in listofAgreements
             Where i.ClientID == j.ClientID
             select  new CustomList{
                  FullName = i.FullName ,
                  AgreementID = j.AgreementID
             }.ToList();
```

Now you can use `Custom` to bind it to your `DropDownList`:

```
myDropDownList.DataSource = Custom ;
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "AgreementID";
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "FullName";
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Comment: I did, but i have an error: DataBinding: Agreement' does not contain a property with the name 'FullName'.

Comment: @pepe Check out the Updates.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your controls (though I think this is a default behavior), you can also do this by overriding the ToString() method for your object.  Normally, this would give a string representation of its type, but if you change the return value to be the desired property, that will be the value of ToString().   If you then bind to something like IEnumerable lstAgreements, you don't even have to property search.  The value for the dropdownlist item will be the object, and the text will be its ToString() output.

Pseudo:

```
prop int AgreementID
prop int ClientID
prop DateTime Date
prop ClientObject CO;

public IEnumerable<Agreement> GetAllAgreements()...

public override string ToString()
{
   return this.CO.FullName;
}


-----------
mydropdown.DataSource = GetAllAgreements(); Databind();
```